# assigning x amount of random numbers to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I currently have 64 values (1-64) and each value returns a different outcome.
I have an array setup with a range of numbers

```
var battleships = ['1', '2', '3', '6']
```

which links with

```
if ($.inArray(String($(this).data("value")), battleships) > -1) { 
    $(this).addClass("success").removeClass("pointer");
    }
```

how would i make the array assign (for example) 26 random numbers between 1 and 64 which could then be picked up by the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function to get random numbers between min and max like this:

```
function getRandomBetween(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

And then you can loop 64 times to fill your array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 64; i++) {

    battleships.push(getRandomBetween(1, 64));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDistinctNumbers(count) {
  var values = [];
  for (var i=1; i<=64; i++)
    values.push(i);

  values.sort(function(a,b){return Math.round(Math.random() * 2) -1;});
  values.length = count +1;
  return values;
}
```

Basically you fill an array with the values you want, shuffle it around and then reduce its length to fit your needs. If count is larger than 64, the array will be padded with `undefined` values.

If your needs change and for some reason, the 64 gets turned into a large number, while the 24 remains relatively low, it will be faster to simply add random numbers and make sure you don't add duplicates than to sort randomly a huge array, but for now this is the fastest solution.

Here is a JsBin with the code: http://jsbin.com/UwAYACe/1/edit